# Dropdownlist DataValueField in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have multiple items in asp drop down list and I want to set its `DataValueField` to one by one using loop. I did it as follow.

```
int cnt = ddl2.Items.Count;

for(int j=0;j<cnt;j++)
{
    string val = ddl2.Items[j].ToString();
    int datafieldid = // want datavaluefield id here
}
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: The `DataValueField` is the **name** of one of your properties on the objects you're showing in the dropdown list. You need to set that **only once** - it applies to the entire list of objects you're binding to the dropdown list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int cnt = ddl2.Items.Count;

for(int j = 0;j < cnt ; j++)
{   
    string val = ddl2.Items[j].ToString();
    int datafieldid =  ddl2.Items[j].value // want datavaluefield id here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to assign value than you can do it with following code:

```
int datafieldid = ((ListItem)ddl2.Items[j]).Value;
```

or you can iterate listitem directly. Try following:

```
 foreach(var listItem in ddl2.Items)
    {
       datafeildid = listItem.Value;
    }
```

Comment: How exactly is your answer helpful?

Comment: @SonerGönül explained how to get value field

Comment: don't getting your ans.. I want the data value field value which i give while binding drop down list.